# Issue with assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting when calling REST API

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `.Net` console app which manages the `REST API` calls from the website using subdomain for example: api.test.com. It configured and runs on `IIS 10 (Win Server 2019)`. This program is built using `.Net 7.0`. The problem is when I try to call some queries using `REST API`, it displays the following message:

```
{"message":"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The specified file cannot be found."}
```

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\BOne.Ewa.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 53AEC2EC-E2A5-4D76-BC8B-64C513CA5342-->
```

**BOne.Ewa.Api.csproj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Company>BOne.Ewa.Api</Company>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <InformationalVersion>1.0.0</InformationalVersion>
    <Product>BOne.Ewa.Api</Product>
    <AssemblyTitle>BOne.Ewa.Api</AssemblyTitle>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion>7.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="FakesAssemblies\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="FakesAssemblies\**" />
    <None Remove="FakesAssemblies\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="BOne.Ewa.Api.Common">
      <HintPath>..\BOne.Ewa.Api.Common\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0\BOne.Ewa.Api.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson">
      <HintPath>lib\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi">
      <HintPath>lib\Microsoft.OpenApi.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog">
      <HintPath>lib\Serilog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console">
      <HintPath>lib\Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile">
      <HintPath>lib\Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger">
      <HintPath>lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen">
      <HintPath>lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI">
      <HintPath>lib\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Backup\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\AutoController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\AutoModelController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\BinaryController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\ChooseTariffController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\ContractAttachmentController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\ContractController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\ContractPaymentController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\ErrorController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\LinqPayController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\PlaceController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\Result.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\SalepointController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\TariffsController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\TemplateController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\TerritoryController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Controllers\UserController.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Program.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Backup\Startup.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Core.System.Configuration.Install" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes" Version="16.11.230815" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.Debug" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalDesignTimeBuildInput Remove="FakesAssemblies\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried different solutions but all failed for me. Any ideas how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Great!

I have fixed it by installing `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package using `NuGet`. Now, all `REST API` calls working well on the website. This issue is resolved. Thank you.